# How do I center align text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, alignment

This code works fine, but i want to center align the Welcome, '+name so that it displays at the top center. Here is what i have so far:

````
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>prompt demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='demo'> </h1>
<script>
  var name=prompt('Please enter your name.')
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='Welcome, '+name
</script>```
````

Comment: Consider using CSS instead. It’s the better tool for the job.

Comment: please check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).. i think it may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>prompt demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='demo'> </h1>
<script>
  var name=prompt('Please enter your name.')
  var h1Element = document.getElementById("demo");
  h1Element.innerHTML='Welcome, '+name;
  h1Element.style.textAlign = "center"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you should make a variable called 'welcomeText':

```
var welcomeText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Welcome, ' + name;
```

Then, this code will align the text in the center:

```
welcomeText.style.textAlign = "center";
```